# Программная эмуляция работы в одностраничном веб-приложении

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование, test-automation

Требуется написать программу, которая будет загружать веб-сайт, представляющий из себя одностраничное веб-приложение, нажимать на элементы управления, заполнять формы и перехватывать содержимое AJAX-запросов.

С помощью каких технологий/фреймворков это можно сделать? Попробовал поработать с casperjs+phantomjs, но скорость их работы разочаровала.

Comment: "Попробовал поработать с casperjs+phantomjs, но скорость их работы разочаровала." - вам шашечки или ехать? Полноценная эмуляция браузера полноценно эмулирует браузер, и, естественно, скоростью не отличается.

Comment: У меня получилось так, что браузер работает быстрее, чем casperjs.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте связку Meteor.js,  cucumber.js и пакета Velocity. Очевидно,  что тесты в эмуляторе бузина должны быть максимально асинхронны и распараллелены,  тогда можно добиться приличной скорости,  плюс тестирующая программа должна запускаться на том же сервере,  что и тестируемая,  чтобы избежать задержек в соединии.

Answer (score 0):

Автоматизацию тестирования можно проводить при помощи готовых инструментов, писать новые в большинстве случаев не требуется.

Можете попробовать Selenium WebDriver из проекта [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), он имеет обёртки, позволяющие формулировать правила тестирования при помощи различных языков программирования (Java, Python и пр.).

Суть работы вкратце: вы описываете тесты в виде набора инструкций; веб-драйвер запускает браузер (или несколько), исполняет в нём упомянутые ранее инструкции (фактически эмулируя действия пользователя) и докладывает о результатах.

Таким образом, изучив возможности данного инструмента, можно тестировать практически любые веб-приложения, в том числе одностраничные.

Comment: Однако, на сколько я помню, селениум не сможет перехватить аякс!?

Comment: @GenaMoroz Если вы про ответ сервера, то это можно реализовать. Однако, такой подход будет потиворечить идее тестирования чёрного ящика. Селениум работает с тем, что видит обычный пользователь — ajax такой пользователь не видит, но [зачастую] видит отражение пришедших данных в интерфейсе страницы.